# How To Upload Android Library For Private Use Only?

Tags: java, android, maven, github, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android app but require to create two Different copies of it with different package names. The reason for wanting two package names is that I want to upload them to two different Stores which requires the developer to provide a different package name.

To simplify the update process and fixing the issues I thought of dividing my code to different libraries.

I have now created an android library and now want to upload it so that I can simply use the library in my projects by simply adding the line `compile com.adc.aaa...`

But I do not want those library to be accessible to other developers either directly of maybe through google Search. Is it possible to achieve this?

These are few links which I have visited regarding this matter

1) https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

2) https://mayojava.github.io/android/library/creating-and-distributing-your-own-android-library/

Can anyone please help.

Comment: You can simply create a module and add that library as the module, there's no need to upload it do bitray to make it available publically if you don't want to share it. You'll still have a compile "something" but it will be local

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Thanks. But do you mean that I should add the library like `aar` or `jar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suposing your module in android studio is called "`library`" you can simply add the module to your app project locally without the need to upload it to bitray.
You can add a local module as a depedency to your project using AS or manually:

**1) Using AS:**

Go to `File -> Project structure`. Click on the app module and then depedencies, click on the plus sign and then choose `3 - Module Dependency`. If you library is in the same folder as your app it'll show up there. Just select it and it will be added as a depedency like the other compile dependencies.

**2) Manually**

In your settings.gradle file add:

```
include ':app', ':library'
```

In your app leve build.gradle:

```
implementation project(':library')
```

If you library module is somewhere else you can inport it to your project using:

```
File -> New-> Import Module
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer. Just one more question, suppose I make any change to the code of library will the change also take place to the library module which has been added to the main app. Or will I have to re add the module?

Comment: You won't need to readd the module, you'll only need to rebuild (sync gradle) :). That's another advantage, because if you uploaded it to bitray you'd need to reupload and wait for the distribution process.

Comment: Thank You very much for the help. Really informative and well explained answer.

Comment: Tried `File--> New --> Import Module` and then AS asked me to add it as dependency, did that also. But now when I Am changing the code in the Library which is somewhere else it is not changing in the project module. Can you please help on how to update the code of library in my project also.